# Change Title Bar Color in Microsoft Office365 Applications

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, colors, office365, color-theme

I have Microsoft Office 365 and each application has its own color for the title bars. For example, Excel is a solid green:

[image]

Outlook is blue:

[image]

OneNote is purple:

[image]

and so on.

Is there any way to arbitrarily change these colors? **For example, if I  wanted to make the outlook title bar a bright red instead of blue, how would I do that?** Or is it impossible? Ideally admin privileges would not be required.

Answer (score 2):

Office have become pretty restrictive as regarding the title bar,
although the Office developers probably see this as an evolution.

You may change the title bar colors of Office in menu
*File > Options > General*,
under "Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office*,
field "Office theme".

Your options are :

- Colorful : The one you have now
- Dark Gray : All titles are in this one color
- Black : Ditto
- White : Ditto
- Use system setting : Also the one you have now
  according to my test.

Comment: This answer is even more relevant now as the default Microsoft 365 application theme is now bland, indistinguishable grey. It's unclear who it helps to remove the distinct identities of applications, especially as we're task and context switching every minute.